# I don't know why I get two backslashes (python)

Tags: python

```
t = '.EA.B2.80.EB.A7.88'

t = t.replace('.','\\x').lower()

string1 = b"\xea\xb2\x80\xeb\xa7\x88"

print(string1.decode("utf-8"))

string2 = bytes(t, "utf-8")

print(string2)

print(string2.decode("utf-8"))
```

String1 returned the decoded value I wanted, but string2 returned two backslashes. I think string1 and string2 are not different but wonder why string2 returns two backslashes. Can anybody answer this? Thank you for reading!

Comment: That's because the backlashes are actually part of the value of `t`. In `string1`, the backslashes are just part of the `bytes` literal syntax, not actual characters in the resulting `bytes` value.

Comment: Oh that's why. Thank you so much! Then is there any way to fix string2 to work as string1?

Answer (score 0):

In `string1`, the backslashes are part of the *syntax* of a `bytes` literal, used to produce the correct bytes in the resulting value.

You are adding literal backslashes to the *value* of the string `t`.

I'm not sure this is the best solution, but you can convert `t` to a sequence of `int` values which can be passed to `bytes`.

```
string2 = bytes(int(x, 16) for x in t.strip(".").split("."))
```

Update: there is something simpler:

```
string2 = bytes.fromhex(t.replace(".", ""))
```